# same queries different db slightly different explain

Tags: mysql, explain

On my production which is running slower than sandbox. this is the explain

production:

```
    id  select_type  table    type    possible_keys  key      key_len  ref                               rows  Extra                                         
------  -----------  -------  ------  -------------  -------  -------  ------------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       ap       ALL     product id     (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)                           35247  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
     1  SIMPLE       Product  eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  8        epic.ap.product_id                   1  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       pp       eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  8        epic.Product.parent_product_id       1  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       v        eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        epic.Product.vendor_id               1  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       mopf     eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        epic.Product.id                      1
```

sandbox:

```
    id  select_type  table    type    possible_keys              key      key_len  ref                               rows  Extra                                         
------  -----------  -------  ------  -------------------------  -------  -------  ------------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       ap       ALL     product id                 (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)                           35522  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
     1  SIMPLE       Product  eq_ref  PRIMARY,parent_product_id  PRIMARY  8        epic.ap.product_id                   1  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       v        eq_ref  PRIMARY                    PRIMARY  4        epic.Product.vendor_id               1  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       mopf     eq_ref  PRIMARY                    PRIMARY  4        epic.Product.id                      1  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       pp       eq_ref  PRIMARY                    PRIMARY  8        epic.Product.parent_product_id       1  Using where
```

I've checked the indexes and they are all the same, but sandbox executes in about 1.2 sec avg and production averages 5.1 sec.  I check that you can force index on other questions but I'm not sure how it applies for mine.

The differences between the 2 explain is that the table order is different and also mopf in production shows no Using where. I'm not sure if it's important or not.

Extra Notes:

Sandbox Hardware is Core i5-3330 8GB, non SSD

Sandbox OS is

Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1

MYSQL is version        5.6.14

Production OS is

Production Hardware is Phenom II X4 965 3.4ghz, 4GB, non-SSD

Windows 7 Business Edition Service Pack 1

MYSQL is version        5.5.8

Production is 75 process, 0% cpu, 48% physical memory while

Sandbox is 128 process, 2% cpu, 79% physical memory.  sandbox is my workstation

Table Counts:
sandbox:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM amazon_products;

35522

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products;

45122

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parent_products;

40528

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vendors;

117

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM magento_oos_product_flags;

1093
```

production:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM amazon_products;

35208

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products;

45189

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parent_products;

40585

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vendors;

117

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM magento_oos_product_flags;

414
```

Comment: What are the OS and mysql version for each?

Comment: I added in the notes at the bottom

Comment: Are there significant differences in the total number of rows for each table between the two DBs? You may want to try using OPTIMIZE TABLE or ANALYZE TABLE to update the statistics

Comment: I've added the counts of the tables in the question

Comment: Sorry I don't have a simple answer for you. Just suggesting the things I would look at in your situation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  I'm uploading sandbox data to production in another database and running it on the same environment to eliminate it being a data/environment issue

Comment: What sort of hardware are they using? Particularly what type of disk? An SSD vs a spinning disk could be a significant performance difference. Also, what sort of I/O, memory and CPU load is there on production? Finally, mysqlnd is not your MySQL version, that's the MySQL driver used by PHP. You can get your MySQL server version with `show variables like 'version';`.

Comment: I've updated the info with the correct MySQL version thanks. Hardware on production is a little outdated.

Comment: It's most likely data issue although I'm not sure how I can identify which tables.  How can I post the table structure so we can eliminate it being table/index structure?  I uploaded sandbox data onto the production and ran the query and sandbox data on production hardware gave me 2.1 sec avg while production data on production hardware gave me 5.6 sec.  There's still a chance that the table structure could be a little difference since I did a synch from sandbox to production so I want to eliminate that as a possible reason if I can

Comment: For what it's worth, I found the following info on performance improvements from 5.5 to 5.6: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/whats-new-in-mysql-5.6.html  It would be interesting to see if upgading your production system makes a difference. Also don't overlook the statistics point - the optimization engine makes it's choices of how to process a query based on the stored statistics for the tables. These can get muddied by lots of inserts, deletes, index changes, etc. Try refreshing them.

Comment: I did run analyze and optimize table but it just said that it won't work and status is okay.  Eeven if there's improvements from 5.5 to 5.6 the fact that i uploaded data onto the same environment, same server, different database same query and it ran faster on sandbox data than production data on the SAME server leads me to believe it's data/structure issue.  If there's a thorough way to test and confim this i'd like anyone's output